# Converting an Array to String and getting a substring

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, substring

I initiated a numerical array inside a JavaScript and to converted it into a string using `join` but when I try to get a `substr`, it doesn't to work. There seems to be a technical error. Please help!

```
var array = [85, 13, 7, 42, 78, 9];
$("#div1").html("<b>This is the original array:</b><br><br>" + array.join("<br>"));

$("#div2").html("<br><b>This is the converted string:</b><br><br>" + array.join(""));

$("#div3").html("<br><b>The substring (from 0 to 3) is:</b><br><br>" + array.substr(0,3));
```

NOTE: `div1`, `div2`, `div3` are 3 seperate divs with ids respectively. That's where I want to display the results.

Comment: You're calling `substr` on the array and not on the result of `array.join`. The `join` function does not modify the array, it returns a `string`

Comment: you mean if i save the result of `array.join` in a `var result` and then perform a `var.substr()` , it should work?

Comment: Yes, it should, unless there's something else wrong with your code.

Comment: ok i got it. this worked `array.join("").substr(0,3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `substr` on the array and not on the result of `array.join`. The `join` function does not modify the array, it returns a `string`

You have to assign the result to a variable and call `substr` on the resulting string value.

```
var joined = array.join("");
joined.substr(0,3); // this will work
```